# Installing python module bottleneck error

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm trying to install the bottleneck python module and I'm getting the following error:

$ pip install bottleneck

```
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1728:0,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:15,
                 from bottleneck/src/func/func.c:314:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:11:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ufuncobject.h:311:0,
                 from bottleneck/src/func/func.c:315:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:236:1: warning: ‘_import_umath’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
i686-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
```

I've got the correct versions of numpy (1.7.1) and Python (2.7.5)

I've tried to fix it by updating cython amongst other things without any luck.

Can anyone shed some light on how I can fix this?

Comment: try updating numpy since the warning message is saying  "Using deprecated NumPy API"

Comment: I think the main problem is in the ' warning: ‘_import_umath’ defined but not used ', that's primarily what I am trying to resolve

Answer (score 0):

I have two very similar machines, same version of Python, NumPy, Cython, etc, one produces the same error yo mention, the other installs Bottleneck 0.60 fine.

With the problem machine, I was able to install 0.70 without any issues, but I don't know what the problem was with 0.60.

The install process spends a lot of time without outputing any message after the Deprecated API message when installing successfully, so I have a feeling the messages issued prior to the compiler getting a SIG_TERM are not relevant to the error.